# How to change the way to show a field in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, dataset

I have a enum field that is stored as integer in database. e.g. 1 means dog, 2 means cat.

I want to show the real name instead of the integer when I display the data, what is the best practice to do this in WPF?

I have tried to change the value in the DataSet like this `row["TYPE"] = Name[row["TYPE"]];` but it doesn't work (unmatched data type).

The data is obtained with this ComboBox, and the datatype is `int`.

```
<ComboBox Height="23" Name="typeSelectComboBox" Width="190">
            <ComboBoxItem Tag="0" Content="Select" />
            <ComboBoxItem Tag="1" Content="Foo" />
            <ComboBoxItem Tag="2" Content="Bar" />
            <ComboBoxItem Tag="3" Content="Cat" />
            <ComboBoxItem Tag="4" Content="Dog"  />
</ComboBox>
```

Here is how I display the data.

```
        string sqlStr = "select * from AREA";
        OracleDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(sqlStr, db.Connection);
        DataSet systemDataSet = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(systemDataSet);

        if (systemDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            /* this doesn't work.
            foreach (DataRow row in systemDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
              //  row["TYPE"] = Name[row["TYPE"]];
            } */
            areaListGrid.ItemsSource = systemDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        }
```

The areaListGrid is just a basic `ListGrid` that hold the data, no special configuration.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
      IsReadOnly="True"
      Grid.Row="1" Height="484" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,4,0,0" Name="areaListGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="668">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding  ID}" Header="ID" MaxWidth="30" FontSize="12" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=NAME}" MinWidth="50" Header="Name" FontSize="12" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=TYPE}" MinWidth="10" Header="Type" FontSize="12" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=DESCRIPTION}" MinWidth="300" Header="Location" FontSize="12">
        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a purely XAML-based approach that would map a value of one type to a value of another type. However:

- By default, a binding in WPF of an `enum` type to a text object, like `TextBlock.Text`, `Button.Content`, etc. will use the `enum` value name. In that case, there's nothing for you to do. The value name will be shown as the bound value automatically.
- If for some reason you are binding not to something actually typed as the `enum`, but as a plain `int`, you should be able to implement an `IValueConverter` that does the mapping, and which you use in the binding declaration of the display object.

If you will provide [a good, minimal, complete code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the essential part of your binding (i.e. the `enum` type and some XAML that displays it), a more specific answer could be provided.

**EDIT:**

Unfortunately, the code example in the question isn't complete. That said, addressing what appear to be a couple of the basic issue…

> "I don't know how to bind enum to a ComboBox yet"

This "just works". For example, here is a simple XAML form with a `TextBlock` to display the current enum value in the `MainWindow` object, and a `ComboBox` where the `Tag` property is assigned to the enum value itself, as is the `Content` property:

```
<StackPanel>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=mainWindow, Path=Value}" />
  <ComboBox SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" SelectedValuePath="Tag">
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="{x:Static local:Fruit.Apple}" Content="{x:Static local:Fruit.Apple}" />
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="{x:Static local:Fruit.Orange}" Content="{x:Static local:Fruit.Orange}" />
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="{x:Static local:Fruit.Banana}" Content="{x:Static local:Fruit.Banana}" />
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="{x:Static local:Fruit.Kiwi}" Content="{x:Static local:Fruit.Kiwi}" />
  </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

(Assume declared `enum Fruit { Apple, Orange, Banana, Kiwi }`, of course)

Note the syntax for using the specific `enum` values: `{x:Static local:Fruit.Apple}`. The `local` refers to the `enum`'s namespace, which is declared in an `xmlns` attribute for the XAML root element (like any XAML namespace), and of course the `enum` value itself is specified as you would in C# (i.e. `<enum name>.<enum value>`).

The `TextBlock` binds directly to the property, which has type `Fruit`.

The XAML compiler and WPF runtime handle all the rest, converting the `enum` values to their names when they are displayed to the user, while using the actual `enum` value when dealing with the values in code.

The `Window` class looks like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Fruit Value
    {
        get { return (Fruit)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }
    public static DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(Fruit), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(Fruit.Apple));

    private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;

        Value = (Fruit)comboBox.SelectedValue;
    }
}
```

I.e. a normal `DependencyProperty`-based property, and an event handler to update the property value when a specific `ComboBoxItem` is selected.

It's not clear from your code example how your `DataAdapter` is configured. But hopefully it's set up to automatically convert the integer in the DB to the `enum` type value in the row. This would be ideal, as then you can just bind the table view directly to the WPF UI object.

If it's not currently set up that way, I'd focus your effort on doing that. But if you really want, you should be able to add an `IValueConverter` to the binding used to display the table rows in your WPF UI. Again, with the question lacking any detail regarding the `areaListGrid`, I can't really say just how exactly you'd do that. But it would work like any other `IValueConverter`: just write the converter to map from the `int` in the DB data to the `enum` name and use that in whatever binding you have for the DB column for that value.

**EDIT #2:**

If you are actually not using an `enum` type, you can implement an `IValueConverter` to handle the explicit conversion. For example:

```
class Int32ToValueNameConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<int, string> _intToName = new Dictionary<int, string>()
    {
        { 0, "Apple" },
        { 1, "Orange" },
        { 2, "Banana" },
        { 3, "Kiwi" },
    };

    private static readonly Dictionary<string, int> _nameToInt = _intToName.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Value, kvp => kvp.Key);

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is int && targetType == typeof(string))
        {
            string result;

            if (_intToName.TryGetValue((int)value, out result))
            {
                return result;
            }
        }

        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string text = value as string;

        if (text != null && targetType == typeof(int))
        {
            int result;

            if (_nameToInt.TryGetValue(text, out result))
            {
                return result;
            }
        }

        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

You might use the above in XAML like this:

```
<StackPanel>
  <Button Content="Increment Int" Click="Int32Button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
  <TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
      <Binding ElementName="mainWindow" Path="Int32Value">
        <Binding.Converter>
          <local:Int32ToValueNameConverter />
        </Binding.Converter>
      </Binding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
  </TextBlock>
  <TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
      <Binding ElementName="mainWindow" Path="Int32Value" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
        <Binding.Converter>
          <local:Int32ToValueNameConverter />
        </Binding.Converter>
      </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
  </TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Clicking the button will rotate through the integer values, displaying the result in both the `TextBlock` and the `TextBox`. Entering a valid value name in the `TextBox` will result in updating the bound property, which of course will update the `TextBlock` to reflect the change.

The code-behind to support the above example:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public int Int32Value
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(Int32ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(Int32ValueProperty, value); }
    }
    public static DependencyProperty Int32ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Int32Value", typeof(int), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    private void Int32Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int newValue = Int32Value + 1;

        if (newValue > 3)
        {
            newValue = 0;
        }

        Int32Value = newValue;
    }
}
```

I trust you can apply the above binding example to your own `DataGrid` scenario and will forgive that I did not feel like going to the effort of producing the self-contained `DataGrid` example that your question should have, and on which I could have based an answer had it been provided.

Comment: Thank you! I have updated the code. I used `int` as the datatype and I know this might not be the best practice, but I don't know how to bind `enum` to a ComboBox yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience. I might make a mistake by mention enum. Actually I didn't use `enum` type at all (because I don't think I need to at first), all I have done is trying to show the names (string) to user and maintain the data as `integer` in code and database. That is what I usually do when I was using dynamic typed language. But now in C# I cannot change the `integer` field to `string` directly. I am trying to implement `IValueConverter `, all these things are new to be cause I am still a novice.

Comment: @leetom: You certainly can use `IValueConverter` to explicitly handle conversion between `int` and some string value. But IMHO, it seems like this would be a good time to declare an `enum` type that matches the `int` values in the database, and use that. After all, as you can see above, if you do it that way, the WPF does all the heavy-lifting for you. I'll add an example of `IValueConverter`, and you'll see it's not _very_ hard, but it's certainly more work than it would otherwise be, and using an `enum` will have benefits elsewhere in your code as well.

Comment: It's so kind of you, I got things worked with `IValueConverter`. Thank you!